# Are there any instant-messaging clients for server?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, instant-messaging

I have Virtualbox based Ubuntu server and I have used Google to get answers for Server based IM and got it as Jabber. But it is confusing to me. I would like someone to suggest me an instant-messaging client for servers.

The answer doesn't necessarily have to be only Jabber. As long as the solution allows me to login into my Google account for chatting in the server, I would be fine. And, I don't have any `xorg` installed and I don't want to install it either because I have very low RAM for my main system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[finch](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/finch) [image: Install finch]

It's a text-based IM client that uses libPurple - the same core as Pidgin. Here are some screenshots

[image: addaccount]

[image: buddylist]